# Inserting html content from b.php into a div in the included a.php

Tags: php, html

I have 2 files. `a.php` and `b.php`.
a.php is a template which I am including in `b.php`.
Here are the contents of `a.php`:

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

Here are the contents of `b.php`:

```
<?php
include ('/a.php');
?>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

How do I insert the

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

into

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

?

The reason Im asking this is because I have a login php file and I have the form in it. I want to insert it into my template's main div section.

Is this possible or will I have to just copy the template and paste it into the login php file?

Comment: I guess those two files are a bit more complicated than what you're showing? otherwise, why use two files at all, just write the html where you want it to be?

Comment: `b` includes `a`, and you want to include `a` into `b`? WUT?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I could do that, but to keep it clean looking (ie smaller files) I'd like to link include the template seperately. If it's not possible then I will just copy paste the webpage file into the login file.

Comment: @u_mulder b.php has a lot of php code and is a webpage on its own but without content. The content is in a.php, but I would like to insert the form in b.php into the main content of a.php instead of copy pasting a ton of stuff. If this isn't possible, meh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually handle this by giving the template the values that should be inserted into the placeholders in the template. As the include inherits the current scope of the location where include happens, for your example you'd do

```
$content = "<h1>Hello</h1>"; 
include("a.php");
```

.. and then have `echo($content)` in `a.php`. I'd strongly suggest using an actual template library to make this more structured for yourself.

Since `include` inherits the current scope, you can wrap it in a function (or a class and call a method to render a template) to avoid symbols leaking into the global scope. This is what most template engines do in some form (or rewrite the accessors / variable names on parsing, if they use a specific syntax - i.e. something like Smarty).

This particular case could probably also be solved by having a header you include that contains the `<div ..>` part, and a footer that contains the `</div>` part, which you include / wrap around your content.